# bash string split by delimiter breaks on empty value

Tags: bash

I have a variable like `LINE=foo,bar,,baz`

I tried to split this with delimiter `,` using 2 different techniques:

1. `array=(${LINE//,/ })`
2. `array=($(echo "$LINE" | tr ',' '\n'))`

`echo ${array[2]}` should return an empty value but it returns *baz*
(Both treat *baz* as the 3rd value when it should be the 4th instead.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with `read -a` and an alternate delimiter:

```
IFS=, read -a array <<<"$LINE"
```

Note that since the assignment to `IFS` is a prefix to the `read` command, it only applies to that one command, and you don't have to set it back to normal afterward. Also, unlike the ones that depend on word-splitting of unquoted variables, it won't try to "expand" any entries that look like filename wildcards into lists of matching files.

Demo:

```
$ LINE=foo,bar,,baz
$ IFS=, read -a array <<<"$LINE"
$ declare -p array
declare -a array='([0]="foo" [1]="bar" [2]="" [3]="baz")'
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. This works beautifully. There are multiple correct answers. Marking this as correct because of more upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

You are relying on a sequence of whitespace between tokens as the separator, but of course, that will lose any empty strings.

As a somewhat crude workaround, temporarily override IFS:

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
array=($LINE)
IFS=$oldIFS
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/Dd1gUV

Answer (score 0):

By default array treat all 'blank' characters as delimiters. If you need to preserve empty values you have to take care of them first.

```
line='foo, ,bar,,baz'
line=${line//,,/,null,}
line=${line//,[[:blank:]],/,null,}
array=(${line//,/ })

$ echo "${array[@]}"
foo null bar null baz

$ echo "${array[@]//null/ }"
foo   bar   baz
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-mapfile) (or `readarray`, same thing):

```
$ LINE=foo,bar,,baz
$ declare -a PARTS
$ mapfile -t -d, PARTS <<<"$LINE"
$ declare -p PARTS
declare -a PARTS=([0]="foo" [1]="bar" [2]="" [3]=$'baz\n')
```

There's an extraneous newline at the end of the 3rd element, hence the `$'baz\n'` value, so you'd have to handle that (see discussion in comments, though). Not sure where it comes from.

Comment: The newline is added automatically by `<<<"$LINE"`; to avoid that you'd have to use something like `< <(printf %s "$LINE")` instead.

Comment: @GordonDavisson ah, yes, thank you. I should have skimmed the docs on `<<<` a little.

Comment: @GordonDavisson : This was why I suspected as well, but if the newline is added by `<<<`, wouldn't you then see it also by i.e. `printf %s $(cat <<<$LINE)`?

Comment: @user1934428 command substitutions, i.e., `$(...)` remove the trailing newline.

Comment: @user1934428 also, the docs for `<<<` read: "The result is supplied as a single string, with a newline appended [...]".